# Change Group By column order in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting, report-viewer2010

I have a rdlc where I'm building a report.

I'm using a tablix grouping by a field of the tablix dataset, like the following:

[image]

When I fill the report with data and refresh it, it comes out like this:

[image]

Now, I want the first column(wich has the group by by the field "nome_terr") appear not in first place, but by second. The first column has to be "territorio_emp". If it was a normal column, I'd just move it, but being the Group By column I don't know how to do this.

Ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that your Territorio_Emp data is 1-1 related to your Nome_Terr column, you can just group by Territorio_Emp first, then by the Nome_Terr column.

If thats not possible, you can keep it the way it is, but make the width of the group by column 0, so its basically hidden. Just drag the column header separators.